# Upload images in Blocks in drupal admin

Tags: 7, blocks, files

Is there any way through which we can upload images from blocks in admin ? I have imce to upload pictures but if it was there in blocks it would be have been better , i saw many work arounds for this like creating a cck feild of image type then save it as view, instead is there any straight forward approach like upload module for nodes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also uploading images on blocks with a normal editor as TinyMCE and the WYSIWYG module after setting in the right way the module, see my screenshot when i create a block...

[image]

Comment: i installed fck , i over looked this one , it has option for imce from fck that will do

Answer (score 0):

You could use webfm module upload images and then display them using img tag in the blocks.